I get an error because the shapedObject in the Hateoas Web API project returns empty
When I proceeded with break points, I saw that the shapedobject part returned empty, probably that's why I'm getting an error. I wonder if I'm making a mistake when converting to Guid type, could you please take a look?
the code block where I got the error
 private ShapedEntity FetchDataForEntity(T entity, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> requiredProperties)
 {
     var shapedObject = new ShapedEntity();
     foreach (var property in requiredProperties)
     {
         var propertyValue = property.GetValue(entity);
         shapedObject.Entity.TryAdd(property.Name, propertyValue);
     }
     var objectProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
     shapedObject.Id= (Guid)objectProperty.GetValue(entity);
     return shapedObject;
 }

the image I took of the break points


I solved the problem, I wanted to mention it here in case someone else experiences it.
The problem was solved when I disabled the NewtonJson field in my Program.Cs file.
I think it is due to sorting
